# callback interrupt called immediately

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm attempting to play with the GPIO of a rasberry PI 2 to simulate an alarm system, I'm creating a callback function to handle when the state of a sensor has changed. I'm would like to accomplish this by creating a "new zone" for each sensor, I created a class that is to handle this.

My issue is that the "callback" gets called before the state changes. I'm not sure what is wrong. Please keep in mind, I'm pretty new to python. I have been searching for the answer but I'm not really sure what to look for.

thanks.

Main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import CreateZone
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)


front = 6#pin
a = CreateZone.CreateZone(front,"test")
GPIO.setup(front, GPIO.HIGH)
print GPIO.input(front)
GPIO.setup(front, GPIO.LOW)
print GPIO.input(front)
```

CreateZone.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


class CreateZone(object):

    def __init__(self, pin, zone_name):
        pin = pin
        zone_name = zone_name
        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN)
        self.new_zone(pin, zone_name)

    def callback(self, pin, zone_name):
        print "Change!!!"
        print "pin = " +str(pin)
        print "zone = " +str(zone_name)

    def new_zone(self, pin, zone_name):
        GPIO.add_event_detect(pin, GPIO.BOTH, callback=self.callback, bouncetime=300)
```

Output

```
Change!!!
pin = 6
zone = test
1
0
```